# How to implement "String.format()" in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to format add a zero to any value less than 10, so 09. So at the end of the loop, the "total" value will format to numbers less than 10 with a zero.

Here is my code but it still isn't working :

```
int total = 0;

String holder = val + "-" + s + "-" + frame + "-";
    for (int i = 0; i < holder.length(); i++)
    {
        int mod = holder.charAt(i);
        total += mod;
        total = total%100; //get remainder
    }

string totalchk = String.format("%02d", total);
```

Comment: Assign the result of `String.format` to a variable.

Comment: And you probably want to do your formatting after all is said and done, after the `for` loop. If you assign the result of `String.format` to a variable in the second line, your result will be `00` every time.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have updated the code, but I get "cannot find symbol - class var"

Comment: `string` != `String`.